# Compiler warning when switching on an enum

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008

```
enum ENUM(Option1,Option2,Option3);

string func(ENUM x)
{
 switch(x)
 {
  case Option1: return "Option1";
  case Option2: return "Option2";
  case Option3: return "Option3";
 }
}
```

This compiles and works but gives a compiler warning that not all control paths return. However isn't the point that if you use enums properly, this isn't the case? If another ENUM val is added, I want compilation to fail but as long as all cases are covered I want it to compile warning-free.

Is this the compiler protecting against bad casted values, is it just part of C++ and needs to be lived with?

Comment: @Archie: wrong solution, then you don't have a warning if you forget an enum member.

Comment: @Matthieu: That's not entirely best practise. I'd err on always adding a default. If you want a warning that you forgot a value, add an assert or throw an exception in the default case. The compiler isn't there to remind you of things you have to do, it's there to compile your code.

Comment: A compiler that enforces enums _is_ compiling your code _more_ strictly though.

Comment: @Jeff Yates: I strongly disagree, because the cost of catching errors at compile-time is lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if for some reason `x` is neither `Option1`, nor `Option2`, nor `Option3`?

Sure, you could argue that will never happen, but since the method has to return something, you have two options:

- add a `return string("");` at the end.
- add a `default` to the `switch` that returns `string("")`.

As CodeGray points out, the second option is arguably better style. You could also return something other than an empty string.

Comment: +1, you need a default return value, but I'd definitely add a `default` case to the end. I think that's significantly more readable.

Comment: what do you mean with `return null`? If you mean `NULL` then you have other problems because `std::string` does not like `NULL`.

Comment: In C++, a `string` is a value object, so you can't return a null pointer (which, by the way, is named `NULL` in C++). In this case you could use "", however, see my answer to a solution where you don't have to invent bogus return values at all.

Comment: What happens if a `bool` is neither `true` nor `false`... but you don't do `if(b==true){...}else if(b==false){...}else{...}`. An enum is a concrete set of possible values, that's the point of it.

Comment: A `bool` can only be `true/false`. There is no third possibility. I realize your dilemma with the enum, but the compiler has to ensure that the language syntax is correct. If a method returns a string, it MUST return a string in all situations. The compiler realizes that there is a theoretical case in which the method passes through the `switch` without hitting any of the `case` statements. And what then? There is no return value. Hence the error.

Comment: @John - No, unfortunately an enum is not a closed set of values, unless you have used all the bits of the underlying type. It is entirely legal to have the value `Option2|Option3`, which isn't in any case label.

Comment: @Bo: "It is entirely legal to have the value Option2|Option3" - is it really? I never thought of that!

Comment: @John - Yes, it is. With three values in the enum, you have the values 0, 1, and 2. In that case the underlying type must have at least 2 bits to be able to represent the values, and all other values using those 2 bits will be valid (like the value 3).

Comment: I am late to the party, but i think it's better to not use default, but add a return outside of the switch. The reason is that in this case the compiler can give you warning for not covering every enum value after someone added a new value. (for example clang has this warning, i think gcc also.)

Answer (score 11):

In C++, enums are not safe. You cannot expect an enum value to be one of the values defined in the enum declaration:

- it could be uninitialized (thus garbage)
- you could have an improper `static_cast` from a `int`

Therefore, the compiler cannot expect the switch to return, even if you cover all elements of your enum. However, it is truly an error condition, functionally speaking.

There are two ways to react:

- add a `default` case to your `enum`
- add a statement after the switch

In order to choose wisely, remember that the compiler may (if you ask it) trigger a warning whenever a `switch` does not cover all the cases of an `enum`, at the condition that there is no `default` statement. Smart compilers (ie Clang) allow to map warnings to errors individually, which greatly help catching those bugs.

Therefore, you have a decision to take:

- if you want to be notified whenever you forget to change this method after updating the enum, then do not use `default`
- if you want to be able to update the enum and ignore this switch, then use the `default`

Finally, you have to decide how to react, noting that using a runtime error is inconsistent with using a default statement (it's best to catch errors at compile-time whenever possible):

- ignore the error and return some predefined value
- throw an exception (with the enum value, please)
- assert (and thus crash hard in debug, to get a memory dump, and do something else in release, like nothing, or throwing an exception)

My personal fav is a `UNREACHABLE(Text_)` macro, which provokes a memory dump in Debug (so that I get a full trace) and log an error and throw in Release (so that the server stops processing this request, but does not stop responding altogether).

This gives code like such:

```
char const* func(ENUM x)
{
 switch(x)
 {
  case Option1: return "Option1";
  case Option2: return "Option2";
  case Option3: return "Option3";
 }
 UNREACHABLE("func(ENUM)")
}
```

Comment: The first case is specious, because if the value is uninitialized, you have UB and a default case isn't going to help you.

Comment: @Antimony: it's actually more vicious, in Debug mode gcc will give you a `0` (often the first member of the `enum`) while in Release mode, because of optimizations, anything may happen... which often enough results in a garbage value (and, with luck, a warning!). I would not advise relying on it, obviously, since by definition UB is unreliable.

Answer (score 6):

From the compilers point of view, the type of the enum is an integer, so it's still possible that the value of `x` is one of the other cases.

Normally, I would add a `default:` label that triggers an internal error.

Hint: If you wrap the call the the intern error in an infinite loop, you don't have to invent a bogus return value. For example:

```
#define IntErr(x) for(;;) { InternalError(x); }
string func(ENUM x)
{
  switch(x)
  {
  case Option1: return "Option1";
  case Option2: return "Option2";
  case Option3: return "Option3";
  default: IntErr("Unexpected ENUM value");
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise the compiler dumped enums straight to ints, that does explain it... but why does it do that in the first place? Are bools similarly treated or do they maintain their own type?

Comment: How does the infinite loop help anything? Isn't a bogus value better than never completing execution?

Comment: @Jesdisciple, It's not an never completing execution, the function `InternalError` stops the execution. The `for(;;)` ensures that you don't have to write a "dead" `return` statement.